# Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I've been trying to create a new azure function (powershell) which uses managed identity to connect to our exchange online environment.

So as far as I can make out from the documentation I need to use the EXO v3, which I'm doing, and use the following command to setup the connection

Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization < tenantname >

If I execute my function, it throws an exception

```
   Exception             : 
Type       : System.UnauthorizedAccessException
TargetSite : 
Name          : CheckResponseHeadersAndGetNewTokenIfNeeded
DeclaringType : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewEXOModule
MemberType    : Method
Module        : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule.dll
Message    : UnAuthorized
Source     : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule
HResult    : -2147024891
StackTrace : 
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewEXOModule.CheckResponseHeadersAndGetNewTokenIfNeeded(ITokenProvider tokenProvider, HttpResponseHeaders responseHeaders, String errorMessage, String cmdletId, TokenInformation& authHeader, Boolean& isRetryHappening)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewEXOModule.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

So I'm guessing the system assigned identity doesn't have the right permissions to access exchange.
But I don't seem to be able to figure out how to add these permissions.

Comment: Did you check to assign the app role as described in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps#step-4-grant-the-exchangemanageasapp-api-permission-for-the-managed-identity-to-call-exchange-online)?

Comment: yes, I've added the the managed identity to the Exchange.ManageAsApp API and exchange administrator role by execution the powershell scripts
`New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $MI_ID -PrincipalId $MI_ID -AppRoleId $AppRoleID -ResourceId $ResourceID` and 
`New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -PrincipalId $MI_ID -RoleDefinitionId $RoleID -DirectoryScopeId "/"`
as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

> The system assigned identity doesn't have the right permissions to access exchange. But I don't seem to be able to figure out how to add these permissions:

*After adding the role assignments, you must provide directory permissions from Microsoft Graph by visiting path in Portal:*

```bash
Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> API Permissions -> Microsoft Graph API -> Application Permissions -> Add a Permission
```

[image]

***Set Azure AD roles and a function app to the managed identity:***

Navigate to `Azure Active Directory -> Roles and Administrators` -> Browse for "**Exchange Administrator**", and then `Add a permission` for the appropriate user/service principal. You must assign the exchange admin role as described in order to connect to the exchange online PowerShell module from Azure resources.

[image]

**Note:**

1. Make sure that the
   `Function App -> Function (PowerShell core)` has system assigned managed identity enabled.
2. Add the EXOv3 in `requirements.psd1` under `Function App -> Functions -> App Files` with the installed version.
   `'exchangeonline' = '3.*'`

Check the latest version releases in [Powershell gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/2.0.3).

Reference: [Exchange online Powershell](https://o365info.com/install-exchange-online-powershell-module/#:%7E:text=Install%20Exchange%20Online%20PowerShell%201%201.%20Set%20Execution,...%203%203.%20Install%20Exchange%20Online%20Management%20Module), [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps#step-2-store-the-system-assigned-managed-identity-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I could finally get rid of this issue by using EXO-PSModule v3.1.0 instead of v3.2.0...